# How to get rails image location in javascript file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an image in `app/assets/images/` folder which is named `map-marker.png`. I need to get the image location in my javascript file to use it as a map marker.

```
 var image  = "map-marker.png";
    var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `/assets/map-marker.png` in your js file. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions to make it.

Case1:

```
var image  = "/assets/map-marker.png";
var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: image
});
```

Case2:

You save your original file `(your_script.js)` as `(your_script.js.erb)` with the image path helper:

```
var image  = "<%= asset_path('map-marker.png') %>";
var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: image
});
```

You can refer document at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html